# Mass update Wordpress post slug and redirect to the new slug by SQL Query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I tried to change the post slug for a specific post using this query:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_name = replace(post_name, 'make-me-happy','make-me-happy-2')
```

it worked, but it wasn't redirected to the new slug as I did it through the wp-admin dashboard.

Answer (score 3):

You also need to insert into [`wp_postmeta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_postmeta) table your post's old slug besides of your query, if want to get autoredirect. Your query:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_name = replace(post_name, 'make-me-happy','make-me-happy-2');
```

Query for getting autoredirect:

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (1, '_wp_old_slug', 'make-me-happy');
```

`post_id` is the `id` of post, which `slug` you changed. The `meta_value` is your post's old `slug`.

WordPress make redirects using function [`wp_old_slug_redirect`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.4/src//wp-includes/query.php#L847) which hooked to action [`template_redirect`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.4/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L340).

Comment: Works great. Thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a 301 redirect line of code for the single post into your .htaccess file.

Add something like the following into your WordPress installations root folder .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /make-me-happy/ https://yoursite.com/make-me-happy-2/
```